# Realtime React Chat with Firestore, how can I subscribe to the data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Structure]

Hey everyone! I'm super lost rn, I gotta make a chat feature on some app and it's hosted on firebase with the current structure, I just have no clue how to subscribe to all the data.

Using react-firebase-hooks, I can subscribe to the chat list easily:

[image: getting list]

But then, how can I subscribe to all the messages within? Since, for example, I should be able to get a notification from one chat while I'm on another, I managed to get the messages like this:

[image]

But I need to be able to constantly watch all this data

I'm just extremely lost rn, any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `get` you can use `onSnapshot`

you will need to do that within a effect, so that you can unsubscribe from it.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = collection.onSnapshot(docs => ...);
   return unsubscribe;
}, [])
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

update:

note that useCollection is already returning a snapshot, so it might be a better approach to also use `useCollection` for child listeners. Also note, that in that case you will need to render the child hook into a child component - which will also make your app perform better because if your component gets unmounted, also the child listeners get unsubscribed

```
const Root = () => {
   const [chats] = useCollection(firestore.collection("chats"));

   return (
      <ul>
        {chats.map(doc => <Child doc={doc} />)
      </ul>
   )
}

const Child = ({ doc }) => {
   const [messages] = useCollection(doc.collection("messages"))
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Nah, it was more or less the same what you wrote, that onSnapshot is needed instead of get, because it constantly watches for data changes without need of implementing any extra code.While get only returns data once per call.

Comment: intereseting part is though, that useCollection already is a snapshot. But not that straight forward as he is iterating and subscribing to each thing. Hopefully there will be not too many things he is iterating through ...

Comment: Thanks! The snapshot does indeed logs me to the console everytime I update the data, and yeah I would prefer just using useCollection again, but since it's a hook I can't use it on a callback, is there a cleaner way to do this? I don't really like the whole mapping stuff

Comment: well you could have the second useCollection for messages only in the child component. so not on the top level one. then you can use useCollection.

Comment: I thought of that, but that would mean I can only get new messages while the child component is active, no? If possible I want each chat to be listening for changes regardless of which one is active

Comment: this will get very expensive. do not do that! it would be better to have a server side change listener that updates that "timestamp" of the last change instead. this way you will know if there is something new and can show a badge or something.

Comment: Hmm, I see, so to listen for that extra field I can just look at the first chat list, the useCollection one, and then for each of those, check if the last timestamp is different from the ones that im saving on maybe a state or something, and based on that alert of a new message
I mean, just speculating, how does that sound for you? I'd have to talk to the backend dude about adding the extra field

Comment: yeah, the timestamp would be on the parent collection and therefore you would get the correct snapshot on the top level already.